# Converting Iso8601 with non-decimal UTC zone offest

Tags: python, time, iso8601

How do I modify the code below to handle a timezone, note there is no decimal.

`2015-12-22T11:57:11-08:00`, `-8:00` is causing me issues, does epoch time take time zone into account?

```
timegm(datetime.strptime(datestring, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").timetuple())
```

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham not duplicate as parts of the 'normal' time string are missing

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here.

1. If your time doesn't include a microsecond block, this date string will not work with the format string you provided. Just try it without the -08:00 bit. That means you either need to assume that all your times won't have that block or you need to account for both possibilities.
2. strptime does a TERRIBLE job of dealing with ISO8601 offsets. If you look at the formatting guide, you'll notice that you can use %z for +/-HHMM, but ISO8601 time zones (in my experience) are almost always presented with the format +/-HH:MM. And even then %z has a nasty habit of being called a bad directive in the format string.

To answer your question, yes, time zone matters. The UNIX epoch is seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00+00:00. More importantly, even if you correctly assign the `datetime` object's `tzinfo` when you parse the string, `timetuple` will NOT take into account that `tzinfo`. You need to use `utctimetuple`

So now you just need to properly parse the datetime. There are solutions that don't use external libraries, but I find the easiest way to parse ISO8601 date strings is to use the python-dateutil package available via pip:

```
>>> import calendar
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> datestring = '2015-12-22T11:57:11-08:00'
>>> tz_aware_datetime = parser.parse(datestring)
>>> tz_aware_datetime
datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 22, 11, 57, 11, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -28800))
>>> calendar.timegm(tz_aware_datetime.utctimetuple())
1450814231
```